# Redirect on logout and display "You have successfully logged out!"

Tags: php, html

I have a membership service on my website. Currently when someone logs out they are redirected to logout.php that has this code on it:

```
<?php

        //check if the login session does no exist
        if(strcmp($_SESSION['uid'],”) == 0){
            //if it doesn't display an error message
            echo "<center>You need to be logged in to log out!</center>";
        }else{
            //if it does continue checking

            //update to set this users online field to the current time
            mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `online` = '".date('U')."' WHERE `id` = '".$_SESSION['uid']."'");

            //destroy all sessions canceling the login session
            session_destroy();

            //display success message
            echo "<center>You have successfully logged out!<br><a href = '/review-pratt/index.php' class='icon-button star'>Return Home</button></center>";
        }

        ?>
```

Instead of having the users be taken to "logout.php" and viewing a boring page that says they logged out. I want them to be redirected to index.php. That part is easy, I know.

I am wanting a notification bar across the top to appear notifying them that they successfully logged out. I have tried to do this before and never got anything to work. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

**Update**

I have changed the logout.php code to:

```
<?php

        //check if the login session does no exist
        if(strcmp($_SESSION['uid'],”) == 0){
            //if it doesn't display an error message
            echo "<center>You need to be logged in to log out!</center>";
        }else{
            //if it does continue checking

            //update to set this users online field to the current time
            mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `online` = '".date('U')."' WHERE `id` = '".$_SESSION['uid']."'");

            //destroy all sessions canceling the login session
            session_destroy();

            //Redirect with success message
            header('Location: /index.php?msg=' . urlencode("You have been successfully logged out!"));
        }

        ?>
```

and added the following code to my index.php:

```
    <?php

    if ($_GET['msg'])
{
       echo '<div class="success_message">' . base64_decode(urldecode($_GET['msg'])) . '</div>';
}

?>
```

And when I log out I receive this error:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/38/10473938/html/review-pratt/business_profiles/logout.php:19) in /home/content/38/10473938/html/review-pratt/business_profiles/logout.php on line 35
```

Comment: As an aside, for security reasons, make sure you are escaping your variables when inserting them into the database. Look up "SQL Injection", and `mysql_real_escape_string()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: add this at the top: <?php ob_start(); ?>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many solutions to this, but almost all of them require logout.php to pass the message, and index.php to have code to display the message.

My preferred method is to pass the message as a URL parameter. Use [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) to re-direct, use [base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) to shorten the text in the url, and [url_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to make sure that the URL doesn't get junked up.

```
//Redirect with success message
header('Location: /index.php?msg=' . urlencode(base64_encode("You have been successfully logged out!")));
```

Then, on your index.php page

```
if ($_GET['msg'])
{
       echo '<div class="success_message">' . base64_decode(urldecode($_GET['msg'])) . '</div>';
}
```

**Edit:** If your headers have already been sent out (have you `echo`ed out some text on a line above these?), you can use Javascript to do the redirection.

Replace `header('Location: ')` with this: `echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=http://example.com/index.php?msg=' . urlencode(base64_encode('You have been successfully logged out!')) . '">';`

Comment: Ok that worked on redirecting to the index.php but how would you get the message across?

Comment: @user2109152 This should echo out your success message. You'll need to use CSS to style it and to make it into a "banner" across the top. I'd make it a new question if you are unsure how to do this.

Comment: Well your edit does not show the message being carried in the url, I tried adding it like you did in the first one but it only gave me an error.

Comment: @user2109152 Sorry about that. Try `echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=http://example.com/index.php?msg=' . urlencode(base64_encode('You have been successfully logged out!')) . '">';`

Comment: What if the user refreshes the page? The message will still be displayed...

Answer (score 5):

you could do something like this:

```
header('location: index.php?status=loggedout');
```

and in your index.php file just look to see if status is not empty, and show a div with the status like this:

```
<?php 
   if(!empty($_GET['status'])){
          echo '<div>You have been logged out!</div>';
   }
?>
```

also inside that if statement you can clear user session aswell..

Comment: @ user session will be clear before header() in logout page , then how we clear  in if statement.

Comment: @  and this method is by $_GET url variable and if we want it by session then how it will be done.

Comment: @MohitKumar i'd suggest asking a separate question if you're dealing with sessions already.  I know how just don't want to derail the original question/answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use "Noty" plugin to enable notifications on your web-app.
see here: http://needim.github.com/noty/

Implementation should look something like that:

1. Redirect the user to index.php?logout=1
2. Use the Query String parameter to populate a hidden field.
3. Use noty to display the hidden field value when page loads.

Here is a code example:

```
<?php 
   if(!empty($_GET['logout'])){
          echo '<input id="logoutMsg" value="You have been logged out!"  />';
   }
?>

<script>
   var logoutMsg = $('#logoutMsg').val();
   var noty = noty({text: logoutMsg });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect right after the success message, then use the following code:-

```
    <?php

        //check if the login session does no exist
        if(strcmp($_SESSION['uid'],”) == 0){
            //if it doesn't display an error message
            echo "<center>You need to be logged in to log out!</center>";
        }else{
            //if it does continue checking

            //update to set this users online field to the current time
            mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `online` = '".date('U')."' WHERE `id` = '".$_SESSION['uid']."'");

            //destroy all sessions canceling the login session
            session_destroy();

            //display success message
            echo "<center>You have successfully logged out!
            echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0;url=http://url.which.you.want.to.be.redirected.to">';
}
         }
?>
```